# Exponential smoothing not recognizing my data as time series

Tags: r

I have a data set that includes t(time) which ranges from 1-243 and 5 other variables which are separate company stock prices each also containing 243 data points. I want to run exponential smoothing on my variable "HD".  I am trying to run the following command:

```
library(smooth)
smoothhd <- es(mydata$HD, h=10, holdout=TRUE, silent=FALSE, cfTYPE=MSE)
```

However, when I do I receive the following error:

```
The provided data is not ts object. Only non-seasonal models are available.
Forming the pool of models based on... ANN, AAN, Estimation progress: 100%... Done! 
Error in .External.graphics(C_layout, num.rows, num.cols, mat, as.integer(num.figures),  : 
  invalid graphics state.
```

Does anyone have any insight as to what is wrong with my command or what might need to be changed with my data file in order for this command to give me the smoothed data?

Answer (score 0):

It just seems that your `mydata$HD` is not a time series object.
Try run `is.ts(mydata$HD)` and if it is not just coerce it to it with `as.ts(mydata$HD)`.